# «Сберечь значит помочь». Нужно ли тире?

Tags: тире

«Сберечь значит помочь». Нужно ли тире или же никаких знаков пунктуации не нужно вообще?

Answer (score 1):

**Сберечь значит помочь.**

О чём это? Кажется, тема конкурса из Интеренета: https://vk.com/wall-8830886_45033

Это конкурс рисунков и плакатов на тему «Сберечь значит помочь: что могу сделать я и каждый». (Имеется в виду для сохранения энергии и природных ресурсов).

В данном случае бережливость тождественна помощи, слова ***беречь*** и ***помочь*** являются контекстуальными синонимами. Поэтому ***значит*** – это глагол, а не связка,  нет тире и паузы.

**Пояснение**

С глаголом ***значит*** не всё так просто, например: **Простить значит (означает) забыть.** Тире здесь нет, нет и паузы, делается расширенное толкование слова: ***простить*** означает "забыть все обиды".

Но ***значит*** может быть связкой при сравнении двух ситуаций (например, по причинно-следственному значению): **Любить – значит страдать** (если любишь, то страдаешь).

**Нужно различать эти варианты.**

Из словаря:

ЗНАЧИТЬ, 1. что, с инф. или с придат. дополнит. Иметь какой-л. смысл, означать (о словах, знаках, жестах и т. п.). Имя Виктор значит победитель. Кивок головы значит согласие. 3. только 3 л.: значит, значило. (**употр. в зн. связки**). То же, что; всё равно, что. **Простить значит забыть**. Забить ещё гол значило выиграть первенство мира.